# Populate Datatable column with data response form fetch using template

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I am trying to populate a Datatable (PrimeReact) column with a custom data, more specifically an image JSX. Now the source of that image needs to be fetched and validated using multiple fetch calls. My problem here is that since Promises are asynchronous, I am not able to form and return that image tag. I would really appreciate any suggestion on how to achieve this.

Comment: Please help me if anyone have any idea about it. Also it may also help me if anyone can guide me on how to access Datatable column outside the **render()** call from another **function()** just like we can access any element by `document.getElementById('id')`.